# db.createRole with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-roles

As per documentation of [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html), there is no way to create a role with MongoDB.

I want to perform role creation with `MongoDB`

```
db.createRole()
```

Though, I could see some external libraries doing a similar approach but not exactly the same as above and also some of those are not maintained

[mongoose-authorization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-authorization)

[mongoose-permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-permission)

[mongoose-role](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-role)

Any best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node js you can achieve it like this

```
await db.command({
         createRole: 'newTestRole', 
         privileges: [
             { resource: { role: "read",  db: 'dbname', collection: "my_collection" }, actions: ["find"] }
        ],
         roles: []
     });
```